# ForEach List<T> Extension method - Value Or Reference Type?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

It seems weird to me. Thought if someone can clear my doubt please.

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
```

Now if we use `ForEach` extension method of collection

```
list.ForEach(c=>c.SomeProperty = SomeValue);
```

So now we can get the updated value. So it seems to be reference type. And Yes `ForEach` takes an `Action` so its reference type. But if try to re-initilize the object inside the `ForEach`  I do not see expected behavior.

```
list.ForEach(c=>{
  if(SomeCondition) // lets consider its always true now.
  {
    c = new SomeClass();
  }
});
```

So after this execution I was expecting fresh list. And should not contain the reference of old object. But if I print the list. I can see the old values.

So why `ForEach` didnt re-initialize the objects in list? While we saw `ForEach` was reference type on value type

Comment: it is just reference type it doesn't pass as `ref`, so you can't assign a new value to the reference.

Comment: You need to project the new object as a select list.

Comment: It's similar to a method where `SomeClass` is passed as argument. It's a reference type but it's not `ref`. If you want to replace the object you need a `for`-loop.

Comment: `c` is a reference to an object in the list. If you change it, you set it to a reference to a different object, but the reference stored in the list remains unchanged.

Comment: also `ForEach` is a common method of `List<T>` and not  an extension

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks.  yes it really make sense.  thanks for clarification.

Comment: @DeepakSharma You are welcome:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether the type of `c` is a reference type or a value type, when setting a variable `c = something`, you are overwriting whatever the variable referred to. So the original object that `c` referred to is no longer referenced. This does not change the list from updating its reference either though, that’s simply not how it works.

If you want to replace some elements in your list by something else, you will need to use `Select`:

```
list.Select(c =>
{
    if (SomeCondition)
        return new SomeClass();

    // default case, return the same element
    return c;
}.ToList();
```

Note that this creates a *new* list, so the old list still contains the same elements.

If you wanted to actually replace elements in the original list, you will have to overwrite the elements in the list by accessing its index. You can do this with a normal `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        list[i] = new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

This will actually mutate the existing list and replace some elements inside of it.

Comment: LINQ is not supposed to cause side effects. If you want to replace the original objects use a `for`-loop. Then you also don't need to replace the whole list (**edit** better now).